# telegraf.js: banChatMember() with custom chatId

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf, telegraf.js

I'm implementing moderation features for a telegram bot, part of it is that the bot should be able to ban a user from multiple groups / channels.

I implemented a command that adds the group it was issued in to a moderatedChats.json, which is just a list of chatIds.
When it comes to the command /gban I want to iterate over this list and let the bot ban the user in each group.

Seems like telegraf's `ctx.banChatMember()` function only allows me to pass in the **userid** and automatically uses the **chatid** the command was issued in.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
bot = new Telegraf(bot_token);

bot.telegram.banChatMember(chatId, userId);
```

Please check line `529` (function banChatMember) of this link https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/v4/src/telegram.ts